# How to Deploy CraftCMS to Dreamhost w/Github

Tags: deployment, workflow, hosting, git

I was recently able to get Craft CMS installed on my local server and I am using MAMP to host locally as I develop the site.

I have never set up a site on my own, so I was hoping someone could give me some instructions on how I eventually post my site.

I already have a domain registered through DreamHost and I am prepared to set up a managed server or VPS, but how will this work in the end?

Ideally, I would have things set up so that I could push everything to github and the site would update automatically. I've used GitHub pages before, so this is the process I'm most familiar with.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend against DreamHost, FWIW -> [How Agencies & Freelancers Should Do Web Hosting](https://nystudio107.com/blog/web-hosting-for-agencies-freelancers)

In any event, to do what you want to do, you'll need *something* that triggers on that when a push to GitHub or what have you happens. If you use Forge as a provisioner, that comes baked in.

If not, you can use a service like [buddy.works](http://buddy.works/) or the like to do it for you. This is discussed a bit in the [Setting up a New Craft CMS 3 Project](https://nystudio107.com/blog/setting-up-a-craft-cms-3-project) article under the **DEPLOYING CRAFT CMS** section.

We also discuss it on the [Website Deployment without Tears](https://devmode.fm/episodes/website-deployment-without-tears) podcast on [devMode.fm](https://devmode.fm/)

...but the general idea is that *something* has to receive a notification from GitHub when you push to a particular branch, to kick off the deployment process for you. Here's what my deployment script looks like on Forge: [My deploy script for Forge](https://twitter.com/nystudio107/status/991416047960981506)